# How to direct the optimizer to perform index scan rather than FULL scan on a table in following query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have created following indexes on this table TDTEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T , but still when I am explaining the plan for the query , the optimizer is doing a FULL Scan , please guide how to fix this so that the cost of reading this entire table gets reduced .

```
CREATE INDEX TDTEMP.FACT_ITEM_TMP_IDX 
  ON TDTEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T
  (ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,SALE_START_DATE,SALE_END_DATE,BU_RU,BU_TYPE_RU)
  
  
CREATE INDEX TDTEMP.FACT_ITEM_TMP_IDX_01 
  ON TDTEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T
  (ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,STATE_NO)
```

Query used is :

```
( SELECT--+ parallel(IT,4)  
                    DISTINCT
                        IT.ITEM_NO              ,
                        IT.ITEM_TYPE            ,
                        DWFACT.REQ_DWP_NO       ,
                        DWFACT.REQ_DWP_ED       ,
                        DWFACT.BU_CODE          ,
                        DWFACT.BU_TYPE          ,
                        DWFACT.FROM_PACK_DATE   ,
                        DWFACT.TO_PACK_DATE     ,
                        IT.SALE_START_DATE      ,
                        IT.SALE_END_DATE        ,
                        IT.PIA_DELETE_DATE      ,
                        DWFACT.DELETE_DTIME AS DWP_DELETE_DATE      ,
                        IT.BU_RU        ,
                        IT.BU_TYPE_RU       ,
                        'PM' AS SOURCE          ,
                        'ACTIVE' STATUS
                    FROM 
                    TDTEMP.FACT_ITEM_TEMP_T IT,
                    TDTEMP.FACT_ACT_PM_T DWPPM ,                    
                    (SELECT t.ITEM_NO,t.ITEM_TYPE,t.REQ_DWP_NO,t.REQ_DWP_ED ,t.BU_CODE,t.BU_TYPE,t.FROM_PACK_DATE,t.TO_PACK_DATE,t.DELETE_DTIME FROM
                    (SELECT     ITEM_NO,
                                ITEM_TYPE,
                                REQ_DWP_NO,
                                REQ_DWP_ED ,
                                BU_CODE,
                                BU_TYPE,
                                FROM_PACK_DATE,
                                TO_PACK_DATE,
                                DELETE_DTIME,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NO,ITEM_TYPE,BU_CODE,BU_TYPE 
                                ORDER BY FROM_PACK_DATE DESC, REQ_DWP_NO DESC ,REQ_DWP_ED DESC) AS RowNumber
                            FROM TDTEMP.FACT_ACT_T 
                            WHERE   DATE '2023-07-11'  >= FROM_PACK_DATE
                            AND     DATE '2023-07-11' <= NVL(TO_PACK_DATE,DATE'9999-12-31')
                            AND     NVL(TRUNC(DELETE_DTIME), DATE '9999-12-31') >=  DATE '2023-07-11' ) t
                            WHERE RowNumber = 1) DWFACT
                            WHERE IT.STATE_NO = 100
                            AND IT.ITEM_NO                      = DWFACT.ITEM_NO
                            AND IT.ITEM_TYPE                    = DWFACT.ITEM_TYPE
                            AND DWFACT.ITEM_NO                  = DWPPM.ITEM_NO
                            AND DWFACT.ITEM_TYPE                = DWPPM.ITEM_TYPE
                            AND DWFACT.REQ_DWP_NO               = DWPPM.REQ_DWP_NO
                            AND DWFACT.REQ_DWP_ED               = DWPPM.REQ_DWP_ED
                            AND DWFACT.BU_CODE                  = DWPPM.BU_CODE
                            AND DWFACT.BU_TYPE                  = DWPPM.BU_TYPE
                            AND DWFACT.FROM_PACK_DATE           = DWPPM.FROM_PACK_DATE
                            AND DWPPM.PM_FUNCTION_ID NOT IN ( 44,45,46,47,48,49)
                            AND NVL(TRUNC(DWFACT.DELETE_DTIME), DATE '9999-12-31') <>  DATE '2023-07-11'
                            AND NVL(TRUNC(DWPPM.DELETE_DTIME), DATE '9999-12-31')  <>  DATE '2023-07-11'
                            AND NVL(TRUNC(IT.PIA_DELETE_DATE), DATE '9999-12-31')  <>  DATE '2023-07-11'
                            )
```

Comment: Your indexes don't appear to be on any tables actually included in the query.

Comment: My suggestion is to look at the execution plan of SQL statements first, and then analyze the use of indexes.

Comment: @pmdba , I have edited the code by mistake pasted incorrect table

Comment: Your indexes don't appear to match the columns used in your query, so the optimizer may not see them as useful. Make sure you update your table statistics after the indexes are created. Also, embedding columns in functions like `TRUNC` or using negative conditions like `NOT IN` or `<>` or `!=` generally makes use of indexes impossible. Can't really speculate more without seeing the execution plan.

Comment: The kind of query you have here should not use indexes. Indexes are not faster in all cases, and Oracle believes they would make your query slower. A full table scan is much faster than index access if the target data is more than a tiny percentage of the table. At a single glance, I can say this kind of query should *should* be doing full table scans and hash joins.